# how to highligting a row when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, jsf

```
<h:dataTable border="1" value="#{InstallerHome.lstMyWork}"
                var="jobsCases" width="100%" id="results" headerClass="tableHeader"
                styleClass="stripe">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:commandLink value="Last Name"
                            action="#{InstallerHome.workSort}" style="color: black; ">
                            <f:param name="SortOrderBy" value="clientLastName"></f:param>
                            <f:param name="IsAscending"
                                value="#{(InstallerHome.isAscending == 'true') ? 'false' : 'true' }"></f:param>
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{jobsCases.clientLastName}" />
            </h:column>
```

In this I want to highlight the row when link is clicked which is having value LastName.

Comment: If the user clicks that `h:commandLink value="Last Name"` in the third row of the table, you want that third row to be highlighted?

Comment: Yes I want to highlight the row when link is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Give an **id** property which you want to highlight, and for the element that needs to be clicked:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('theID').select();
document.getElementById('theID').setSelectionRange(0, 99999999);"
```